# Can't print value from array of objects

Tags: vue.js

Here I am filling the `localStorage`:

```
let storageObj = {};
storageObj.date = (new Date().toLocaleString().replace(", ","T"));
storageObj.url = this.responseURL;
localStorage.setItem(storageObj.date, storageObj.url);
```

In `mounted()` I am iterate all data from `localStorage` like:

```
for(let obj of Object.entries(localStorage))
{
    this.lastpasts.push(obj);
}
```

And placing every Object to `lastpasts` (located in `data() {lastpasts : []}`).

In template I want to print only `url`:

```
<div class="ui divided items" v-for="el in lastpasts">
    <div class="item">
    {{el.url}}
     </div>
</div>
```

But this code do not print nothing. Work only `{{el}}`. It's print in HTML block:

```
[ "24.06.2017T11:55:10", "362e9cc5-e7e6" ]
[ "24.06.2017T12:26:47", "b0f9f20d-7851" ]
```

Browser console do not have any errors.

Comment: Can you please put the result of `console.log(el)` ?

Comment: `ReferenceError: el is not defined     at <anonymous>:1:13`

Comment: Oh, sorry. My mistake. `console.log(lastpasts)` (or lastposts?)

Comment: `lastpasts` because it's code-past blocks.
`console.log(lastpasts)`
`ReferenceError: lastpasts is not defined    at <anonymous>:1:13`

Comment: Here is full code http://past.code123.org/61c68aeb-f4af

Comment: mounted()       
  {       
   for(let obj of Object.entries(localStorage))       
 {       
  this.lastpasts.push(obj);       
 }     
console.log(this.lastpasts);  
  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147508/discussion-between-user1432751-and-m-u).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the chat session we managed to solve his issue.

It was caused by the fact, that he was using Array of Arrays instead of Array of Objects. Because Array can be used only with index, not field name, `{{el.url}}` was not working.

The code to get values from `LocalStorage` had to be changed to:

```
mounted() { 
  for(let obj of Object.entries(localStorage)) { 
    var x = {}; 
    x.url = obj[0]; 
    x.date = obj[1]; 
    this.lastpasts.push(x);    
  } 
}
```

Now, it is possible to use `{{el.url}}`

Comment: Oops i'll remove my answer cuz its the same and +1 for you

Comment: cheers. We were chatting and solving it together when you wrote your answer :)